# CreateHostBuilder Error while trying to run project on a different computer

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I m trying to run a dotnet API project based upon .net framework or .net core (not sure). The only requirement to run this project is to update the path for certificate in the appsettings.json to wherever the API project is stored on local machine. I ran this project on multiple windows 10/11 machines locally and it runs perfectly, but on one local machine i get this error as shown below -

```
InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: FSTProj.FSTClinModule.Domain.MedProfileDomain.IMedProfileDomain Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: FSTProj.FSTClinModule.Domain.MedProfileDomain.MedProfileDomain': Unable to resolve service for type 'FSTProj.FSTClinModule.Core.IHhaUserResolverService' while attempting to activate 'FSTProj.FSTClinModule.Domain.MedProfileDomain.MedProfileDomain'. Microsoft.Extensions.
```

**ConfigureServices()** method in Startup.cs class

```
    using FSTProj.FSTClinModule.Core;
    using FSTProj.FSTClinModule.Domain.MedProfileDomain;
    using FSTProj.FSTClinModule.Infrastructure.Common;

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddDBContext<DBContextVariable>();
        AddDependencies(services);
        DomainDependencies(services);

        var contentRoot = Configuration.GetValue<string>(WebHostDefaults.ContentRootKey);
        var certPath = Path.Combine(contentRoot, Configuration["Certificate:Name"]);
        var signingCertificate = new X509Certificate2(certPath, Configuration["Certificate:Password"]);



        services.AddAuthenticationServices(Configuration, signingCertificate);
        services.AddDataProtectionServices(Configuration, signingCertificate);
        //services.AddAuthorizationPolicies<UserPermissionRole>();

        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "FSTProj.ClinModule.API", Version = "v1" });

            var securityScheme = new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Name = "JWT Authentication",
                Description = "Enter JWT Bearer token **_only_**",
                In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                Type = SecuritySchemeType.Http,
                Scheme = "bearer", // must be lower case
                BearerFormat = "JWT",
                Reference = new OpenApiReference
                {
                    Id = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                    Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme
                }
            };
            c.AddSecurityDefinition(securityScheme.Reference.Id, securityScheme);
            c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
            {
                {
                    securityScheme, new string[] { }
                }
            });
        });

        services.AddSingleton<ITelemetryInitializer, HttpContextRequestTelemetryInitializer>();
        services.AddSingleton(c);
        services.AddOptions();
        services.AddTransient<IFstUserResolverService, FstUserResolverService>();
    }
```

**IMedProfileDomain.cs**

```
namespace FSTProj.FSTClinModule.Domain.MedProfileDomain 
{
    public interface IMedProfileDomain
    {
        List<CDMedProfile> GetMedications(int patientid, int vendorid);
        Task<Response> AddMedication(MedProfileActionRequest request);
        Task<MedicationList> GetMedication(MedicationListCommand command);
    }
}
```

**MedProfileDomain.cs**

```
using FSTProj.FSTClinModule.Core;
using FSTProj.FSTClinModule.Core.DbEntities.FST;
using FSTProj.FSTClinModule.Core.DbEntities.FSTClinModule;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace FSTProj.FSTClinModule.Domain.MedProfileDomain
{
    public class MedProfileDomain : IMedProfileDomain
    {
        private FSTClinModuleDBContext _FSTClinModuleDBContext { get; set; }
        public IConfiguration _configuration { get; }
        private FSTDBContext _FSTDBContext { get; set; }
        private readonly IFstUserResolverService _fstUserResolverService;

        public MedProfileDomain(FSTClinModuleDBContext FSTClinModuleDBContext, FSTDBContext FSTDBContext, IConfiguration configuration, IFstUserResolverService fstUserResolverService)
        {
            _FSTClinModuleDBContext = FSTClinModuleDBContext;
            _FSTDBContext = FSTDBContext;
            _configuration = configuration;
            _fstUserResolverService = fstUserResolverService;
        }

        // rest of the methods and propeties commented
    }
}
```

**IFstUserResolverService.cs**

```
namespace FSTProj.FSTClinModule.Core
{
#pragma warning disable SA1600 // Elements should be documented
    public interface IFstUserResolverService

    {
        int GetPayerId();
        int GetUserId();
    }
#pragma warning restore SA1600 // Elements should be documented
}
```

**FstUserResolverService.cs**

```
namespace FSTProj.FSTClinModule.Infrastructure.Common
{
    public class FstUserResolverService: IFstUserResolverService
    {
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContext;

        public FstUserResolverService(IHttpContextAccessor httpContext)
        {
            _httpContext = httpContext;
        }

        public int GetPayerId(){ }

        public int GetUserId() { }

    }
}
```

What can be the possible reasons this API project fails to run on just this one specific machine ? Possible solutions will also be helpful.

**Update 01:**
the folder structure -

```
    FSTProj.sln
    |
    ├── FSTProj.FSTClinModule.Domain
    │   ├── Domain
    │   ├── IDomain
    │   └── MedProfileDomain
    │       └── MedProfileDomain.cs
    |
    ├── FSTProj.FSTClinModule.Infrastructure
    |   ├── Common
    |   └── FstUserResolverService.cs
    |
    └── FSTProj.FSTClinModule.Core
        ├── DbEntities
        ├── Enumns
        ├── Model
        └── IFstUserResolverService.cs
```

**Update 02:**
Improved stack trace -

```
 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: FSTProj.FSTClinModule.Domain.MedProfileDomain.IMedProfileDomain Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: FSTProj.FSTClinModule.Domain.MedProfileDomain.MedProfileDomain': Unable to resolve service for type 'FSTProj.FSTClinModule.Core.IFstUserResolverService' while attempting to activate 'FSTProj.FSTClinModule.Domain.MedProfileDomain.MedProfileDomain'.
```

Comment: Hi @humbleCodes, for the error, it seems you do not register the service called `IHhaUserResolverService`, but I cannot see any service called it in the `MedProfileDomain` class.

Comment: HI @Rena thnx for responding, I will soon update you with the requirements you mentioned in the previous comment, but the thing that still bugs me is the same codebase runs perfectly on other machines of my colleagues (windows OS) as well as my alternate machine, why is that even a case ?

Comment: @Rena I have updated the question with little more info. Also by some luck I was able to run it last night. But don't know why I m unable to run this again

Comment: have also update the file naming conventions to match with the actual project